# What is the purpose of HttpHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation?

Tags: c#, .net

In the System.Net.Http.Headers namespace, what is the difference between [HttpHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875107.aspx) and [HttpHeaders.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158900.aspx)?

Specifically, what validation is occurring when calling the Add method? The documentation for Add() simply states:

> "The header value will be parsed and validated."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using Reflector, this is what the **TryAddWithoutValidation** method does internally:

```
if (!this.TryCheckHeaderName(name))
{
    return false;
}
if (value == null)
{
    value = string.Empty;
}
AddValue(this.GetOrCreateHeaderInfo(name, false), value, StoreLocation.Raw);
return true;
```

The work happens inside the `TryCheckHeaderName()` function.

It boils down to checking whether the name is not null and whether it matches the RFC for the HTTP protocol (i.e. it contains no invalid characters etc.) as well as checking the header against a set of *not-allowed* headers.

Here's the source-code:

```
bool TryCheckHeaderName(string name)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
   {
       return false;
   }
   if (HttpRuleParser.GetTokenLength(name, 0) != name.Length)
   {
       return false;
   }
   if ((this.invalidHeaders != null) && this.invalidHeaders.Contains(name))
   {
       return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

In contrast the **Add** method has similar behavior with the *exception*(pun intended) that it throws an exception in case the header name fails any one of the conditions in the `TryCheckHeaderName` function.

Comment: This is incorrect. TryAddWithoutValidation will succeed and return true on some input that Add will throw an exception on

Comment: @Gilthans I would have found your comment more valuable if you had exemplified your assertion.

Comment: I remember vividly experiencing a case where Add would fail and TryAddWithoutValidation would succeed, and I now wish I posted the code... I believe it had to do with adding header which is invalid for some HttpMethod

Comment: @Gilthans have you read the answer? How does your experience contradict what I said in the answer?

Comment: "the Add method has similar behavior with the exception(pun intended) that it throws an exception in case the header name fails" - this implies the TryAdd will work exactly the same, only return false instead of throwing an exception

Comment: similar != "exactly the same", but nonetheless I still don't see how that contradicts what happens: in situations where Add would fail and throw, TryAdd would fail but not throw - not much of a difference other than the failure mode

Comment: After spending half an hour to an hour of googling and digging through reflector this answer finally made things clear. It's annoying how poor Microsoft's documentation is on things like this. We're going to give you 8 ways to add headers and give you no real explanation of what it means.

Comment: This answer misses the crucial detail that @Peter Ritchie's shorter answer is about: not parsing the value.

This is crucial because you may want to send values that are deemed invalid by the validation, but _are_ accepted by the target server.

Comment: @MarkLagendijk Please read the answer one more time. It does say that, but with more words. That doesn't really make it incorrect.

Comment: @MikeDinescu I re-read it and the answer only talks about the header _name_, not about the header _value_.
Unless the `it` in the second part of this sentence also means the _value_: "It boils down to checking whether the name is not null and whether it matches the RFC for the HTTP protocol".
If so it should be rewritten, because it is not obvious, and the fact that the _value_ is also validated, is crucial.

Answer (score 3):

`TryAddWithoutValidation` does not try to parse the value it is given to see if it is valid (e.g. valid "type" of value or multiple values for a single-value header).  `Add` first parses the value to perform the previously mentioned checks before trying the add the header value