# Error when contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

Tags: .net, api, http, c#-4.0

I am getting below error when I set the contentType as **'application/json; charset=utf-8'**

*Error Message: HTTP Content-Type header must have a value of application/json.*

This is resolved when I change the ContentType to **'application/json'**

Is there a way that this can be avoided? Because for other API calls, we need  'application/json; charset=utf-8'.
Not sure whether **tryaddwithoutvalidation** can help as I am not aware of what exactly this method does.

Comment: `application/json` does not have a charset parameter. Wether present or not, compliant applications are supposed to ignore it.

Comment: But, in this case, compliant or client api is not ignoring it. it is only looking for application/json while our application sets the contentType as 'application/json; charset=utf-8'. So, is there better solution to handle both the things?

Comment: Yes, approach the developers of the application in question and point to the [media type registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/json) of `application/json`. None of the peers is adhering to specs.

Comment: just a follow up question, so any idea as in when should we use 'application/json; charset=utf-8' like under what circumstances for content type?  Also, would be great if you can shed some light on what  tryaddwithoutvalidation does?

Comment: "any idea as in when should we use 'application/json; charset=utf-8'" Simple: never. As to tryAddWithoutValidation, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990620/what-is-the-purpose-of-httpheaders-tryaddwithoutvalidation) may be of value.